# How to provide velocity command from difference in position?

Tags: ros, drone

I am trying to make my drone follow aruco marker , earlier I was using difference in position multiply by PID value and feeding it that but people over the internet suggested that using velocity command (twist ) would be better , I am not sure how can I do that like what needs to be done with the difference in position I am getting to make it velocity and feed it as twist command to drone. I am a newbie , any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think what they mean is to profile a move from A to B and generate a twist command to follow the profile. Look up "trapaziodal velocity profile" on you favorite search engine.

The reason this will work well is that it will attempt to reach the maximum possible speed safely regardless of distance to the next point, where your method will create effort that varies linearly with distance.

The profile is not based on error as a PID loop is. A PID loop should still be used around maintaining the velocity dictated by the profile where possible.

An alternate method that would be a hydrid between your method and the profiled velocity would be to profile the required position in time and then run the error in position through a PID and convert output to twist. Honestly this method is so close to velocity profiling you may not notice a performance in undemanding applications. The proper choice may depend on if you have better accuracy from your position input or your velocity input.